# Prefilling a form from nested divs structure: front-end design advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am building a list of items, those will be pulled from database and make a nested-div structure about depth of 3, basically there will be a row divided into different sections.

When a user clicks on that row, I want to open modal editor and prefill it with data from that row, basically just copy the content of relevant fields to the modal form.

I am seeing how to do this, but it looks really ugly, basically something like this:

```
$children = $($(this).parents()[1]).find('div');
$modalFields = $("#context-item-editor").find('input', 'textarea');
```

And then I'm gonna refer by indices to each child and match it with relevant field in the form...

I wonder, if there is a better way to approach that? And if not, do find() method always preserves the order of elements?

Here is how looks the row structure:

```
  <div class="row content-item-wrapper">
    <div class="row item-header">
      <div class="col-sm-2 source">
        Source: <a href="http://www.newsru.com/world/20nov2017/soros.html">NewsRU</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 content-item-topic">
        Topic: WW2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row item-body">
      <div class="col-sm-1 content-item-id">
        (135)
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 content-item-date-created">
        12.05.2017
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 content-item-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is modal form:

```
<div class="modal-content context-item-editor">
  <span class="close" id=closeEditor>&times;</span>

  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="topic">Номер в базе данных:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="modalID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="topic">Date and time:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="modalDateTime">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="topic">Source:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalSource">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="topic">Topic:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalTopic">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txt">Text:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="modalTxt"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to advise you without seeing a more complete sample of your code. All I can say is that `$($(this).parents()[1])` is redundant, just use the jQuery object returned from `parents()` directly: `$(this).parents().find('div');`, or if you want the second one specifically: `$(this).parents().eq(1).find('div');`

Comment: Thanks Rory. I've added more of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konstantin,

If you put the click action on '.context-item-editor' you'll be able to navigate through each "HTML object" DOM tree easily

Here's a small simulation of your case : https://jsfiddle.net/n6v522fp/2/
I hope it can help your case.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.content-item-wrapper').on('click', function(){
   $row = $(this);
    $('.modalform').dialog({
      modal: true,
      open: function(event, ui){
        var source = $row.children('.item-header').children('.source').children('a').text();
        var topic = $row.children('.item-header').children('.content-item-topic').text();
        $('#modalSource').val(source);
        $('#modalTopic').val(topic);
      }
    });
  })

});
```

```css
.modalform {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row content-item-wrapper">
    <div class="row item-header">
      <div class="col-sm-2 source">
        Source: <a href="http://www.newsru.com/world/20nov2017/soros.html">NewsRU</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 content-item-topic">
        Topic: WW2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row item-body">
      <div class="col-sm-1 content-item-id">
        (135)
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 content-item-date-created">
        12.05.2017
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 content-item-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content context-item-editor">
  <span class="close" id=closeEditor>&times;</span>
</div>

<form class="modalform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="topic">Номер в базе данных:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="modalID">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="topic">Date and time:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="modalDateTime">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="topic">Source:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalSource">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="topic">Topic:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalTopic">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txt">Text:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="modalTxt"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! Thank you so much!